# Angular mat chips with auto complete not working

Tags: angular, mat-autocomplete

i want to implement the matAutoComplete in my angular project
i gone through some references
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-chips-angularmaterial?file=package.json

but i didn't get any options for autoComplete.

//component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>


<pre>{{fruits|json}}</pre>
```

//component.ts

```
export class ChipsOverviewExample {
visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = false;
  separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  fruitCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredFruits: Observable<string[]>;
  fruits: string[] = [];
  allFruits: any= ['hi','hello','apple'];

  @ViewChild('fruitInput') fruitInput: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
    this.filteredFruits = this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        map((fruit: string | null) => fruit ? this._filter(fruit) : this.allFruits.slice()));
        console.log(this.filteredFruits)
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.fruits.push(value.trim());
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }

    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }

  remove(fruit: string): void {
    const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
    this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {        
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.allFruits.filter(fruit => fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

even i already imported the MatAutocompleteModule package in app.module.ts

Comment: you provided stackblitz link. is this a reference link which you are trying to follow or is this your implementation with the problem.

Comment: yes, this is the reference link which i m following

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

.ts

```
 constructor() {
    this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(search => {
      this.filteredFruits = of(this.allFruits.filter(item =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)
      ));
    });
  }
```

.html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>


<pre>{{fruits|json}}</pre>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-chips-angularmaterial-nxcw6m?embed=1&file=app/chips-overview-example.html)**

Comment: Its not working, the problem is i m not getting any option popup dialog.I think you answered for [object- object], right?

Comment: And also search filter. Have you checked the demo I shared? Is it missing something?

Comment: Yes the demo is working as expected , but the problem is in my case i m not getting that popup for options

Comment: I am unable to understand your issue, can you share it in stackbiltz

Answer (score 1):

[Answer updated to fix second search list]

- https://mat-chips-angularmaterial-zg9mhy.stackblitz.io
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-chips-angularmaterial-zg9mhy?file=app/chips-overview-example.ts

**HTMl CHANGES**

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
  {{fruit.name}}
</mat-option>
```

**TYPESCRIPT CHANGES**

```
private _filter(value: string): string[] {
  const filterValue = value['name'] ?  value['name'].toLowerCase() : value.toLowerCase();

  return this.allFruits.filter((fruit) => new RegExp(value, 'gi').test(fruit['name']));
}
```

Comment: i m not getting , why should i use {{fruit.name}} .in my case its a list of String only.

Comment: this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges when the ctrl dont have any value you are returning this.allFruits.slice() means retruning same allFruits allFruits: string[] = [
    { id: 1,
      name: 'Apple'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Orange'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Banana'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Malta'
    }
  ] array as it is. Please console logs and check what value you are returning . Thank you.

Comment: I think the solution is fully working as per your this query ?? r8.